# Trouble trying to disable L2 cache on BeagleBone Black

Tags: beagleboneblack, u-boot, bare-metal, cortex-a, cortex-a8

First of all, I'm a total beginner on ARM programming. I want to make some analysis with my L2 cache disabled. I'm running a U-boot environment, bare-metal, on my BeagleBone Black and I'm trying to disable the cache following the steps provided on [this link](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0344/k/level-2-memory-system/enabling-and-disabling-the-l2-cache-controller):

> 1. Disable the C bit.
> 2. Clean and invalidate the L1 and L2 caches.
> 3. Disable the L2 cache by clearing the L2EN bit to 0.
> 4. Enable the C bit.

My code is something like this:

```
asm volatile("MRC p15, 0, %0, c1, c0, 0\t\n": "=r"(controlRegister)); //Retrieve Control Register
controlRegister = controlRegister & ~(1u << 2); //change Bit C to 0;
asm volatile ("MCR p15, 0, %0, c1, c0, 0\t\n" :: "r"(controlRegister)); //write new value
```

I know this is only the first step (disable C bit), but I'm having trouble accomplishing it. The problem is, when I try to write the new value and then check if it was written correctly, the value retrieved is 00000000.

In ARM's forum I was told that I need to be on supervisor mode, but on the documentation it says, and I quote, [“Supervisor mode is a protected mode for the OS”](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0344/k/programmers-model/operating-modes) and since I don’t have an OS (I’m running bare-metal), I don't know if there is this “mode abstraction”.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: you are using uboot and baremetal. so that leaves a little confusion.   If you have a binary that you launch from u-boot as if it were a kernel, you are in supervisor mode.  I would think the caches are off until you turn them on?  Is the cache really off.  Does your experiment require l1, or can you do without either?  What if you simply disable caching all together as an experiment to see if you can do that, does it appear to work?   do you require dram, what if you avoid using u-boot (and no dram, etc)

Comment: if you use real assembly instead of inline, what happens?

Comment: @old_timer so, when i check the C1 control register it shows that the instruction cache and the data cache are on. My experiment requires L1 cache, I've already tried to disable all caches and i was unable to achieve it. When i try to write on C1 control register now, my program just stays hanging and does not continues.

Comment: @old_timer , as you commented, I'm launching a binary from u-boot, and yes, I'm on supervisor mode